# REST JSON API Structure for "Mixed Bag"

Tags: json, api, rest

So i'm building an RESTful JSON-based API where one of the results is a "activity feed" of what the user has done (think: Facebook newsfeed).

Sample use case for API:

> Given a user's ID, return the most recent N activities

Where an activity might be: answered a question, favorited a post, wrote a review, etc. Each activity has different information associated to it.

How would one structure this in a JSON response? The clients of the API are both a JavaScript/SPA application and mobile applications (iOS, android, etc)

Few ideas come to mind.

**Have a different sub-model for each type of activity, with a "order" property on each so the client knows which order to display the items in the feed**

E.g - get the 3 most recent activites:

```
{
  "answers": [
    {      
      "createdOn": "2013-09-09T23:24:46.303",
      "order": 1,
      "question": {
        "title": "Loren Ipsum"      
        },
      "answer": "blah blah"
    },
    {      
      "createdOn": "2013-09-09T23:24:46.303",
      "order": 3,
      "question": {
        "title": "Loren Ipsum 2"        
      },
      "answer": "blah blah 2"
    }
  ],
  "favourites": [
    {      
      "createdOn": "2013-09-09T23:24:46.303",
      "order": 2,
      "favourite": {
        "id": 1
        }
    },
  ]
  "totalItems": 30
}
```

The client would then pull out the `order` properties to know which activity to display first.

**Mixed bag of results with "type" property**

```
{  
  "items": [
    {      
      "type": "answer",
      "createdOn": "2013-09-09T23:24:46.303",
      "question": {
        "title": "Loren Ipsum"      
        },
      "answer": "blah blah"
    },
    {      
      "type": "favourite",
      "createdOn": "2013-09-09T23:24:46.303",
      "favourite": {
        "id": 1
        }
    },
    { 
      "type": "answer",
      "createdOn": "2013-09-09T23:24:46.303",
      "question": {
        "title": "Loren Ipsum 2"        
      },
      "answer": "blah blah 2"
    }   
  ]
  "totalItems": 30
}
```

**Have the main response just have the type/id, then seperate endpoints for each activity**

```
{  
  "items": [
    {      
      "type": "answer",
      "id": 332423
    },
    {      
      "type": "favourite",
      "id": 552342
    },
    { 
      "type": "answer",
      "id": 75544
    }   
  ]
  "totalItems": 30
}
```

(..and then `activities/answer/{id}` to get the answer, for example)

Can i get some advice/guidance here? Anyone know how Facebook does it?

Answer (score 0):

Consider supporting this endpoint:

```
GET /activities?mostRecent=25&details=Yes
// or details=No, or True/False
```

If the client requests details, then they get the full activity objects, per your option (2), above. If the client requests no details, the response is a list of the most recent activities:

```
{  
  "items": [
    {      
      "type": "answer",
      "self": "/answers/332423"
    },
    {      
      "type": "favourite",
      "self": "/favourites/552342"
    }
  ]
  "totalItems": 2
}
```

If all the activities were of the same type, it would be preferable to let the query parameter specify exactly what details came down the wire, but that becomes very messy with multiple types coming back. The `details=Yes/No` is a blunt instrument, but I think it's your best option here. I'd suggest making No the default to minimize network traffic - otherwise clients may be getting data they really don't care about.

It's preferable to include the URI rather than just the ID. This lets your server move/change URIs later without breaking the client. Not that it's desirable to do that, but this way if you have to the client still works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My personal preference has always been to stray away from the "querystring/input shaping the response" method. Mainly because the clients are all internal (website, mobile app) and the consumption is (well, should be) consistent across all platforms. In other words, i don't see one client doing `details=yes`, and another `details=no`. Secondly i don't like the idea of different responses for a single resource shaped by the input. Thirdly it obviously adds complexity to the API. Might stick with my first approach